# How to remove "nav-justified" with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create web page with bootstrap.
Then, I used "nav-justified" as follows.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div>
        <ul class="nav-justified">
            <li class="col-md-3">blah</li>
            <li class="col-md-3">blah</li>
            <li class="col-md-3">blah</li>
            <li class="col-md-3">blah</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And on web page, if you arrange size as small, some points "・" appeared.
I want to remove these"・"
Could someone tell me how to solve this problem?

or Are there some way same as "nav-justified" without "・"?

I am so appreciate if you would answer my question.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to set this in your css (or customize bootstrap directly)

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    ul.nav-justified {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't you add the `nav` class to your `ul`

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-justified"> <!-- added the nav class here -->
            <li class="col-md-3">blah</li>
            <li class="col-md-3">blah</li>
            <li class="col-md-3">blah</li>
            <li class="col-md-3">blah</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojNxZm)

PS : I don't think you need to specify the horizontal size of you list element ([codepen without the size specifier](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojNxZm))

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS file:

```
ul.nav-justified {
  list-style-type: none
}
```

This will remove the bullet points from your list.